# MVC - Showing validation message in place of Label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

Suppose this is my view...

```
<div class="control-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
         <div class="controls">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)

         </div>
      </div>
```

In case of error How we can hide the `Label` and display `validation message` in place of `Label`?

Please suggest on this...

Answer (score 0):

You could display the Label only if the ModelState is valid:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @if (this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label" })
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that if you are using client side validation you will also need to hook up to the validate method on the client and toggle the corresponding label visibility as well.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the OP is using client-side validation?

Comment: Nope it won't work. But it's easy to implement. You will have to hook up to the client side validation and hide the corresponding label on the client.

Comment: Yep, it's worth updating your answer to include that as I assume most people nowadays would be using client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Just to compliment Darin's answer, if you are using client-side validation you will need to do something like

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        $('.control-label').hide();
    }
});
```

Otherwise the label won't hide.

It's worth still checking `ModelState.IsValid` when the page loads as well though incase the user has JS disabled.